# Stophe with ejabberd http-bind 404?

Tags: angularjs, ejabberd, strophe

I am trying to connect ejabberd server usigng strophe.I want to use http-bind module but i can not make connection with server.When i try to connect with server, It throws 404 not found error.

> ### error Log
>
> POST http://localhost/http-bind/ 404 (Not Found)Strophe.Bosh._processRequest.sendFunc @ strophe.js:4614Strophe.Bosh._processRequest @ strophe.js:4626Strophe.Bosh._throttledRequestHandler @ strophe.js:4778Strophe.Bosh._connect @ strophe.js:4177Strophe.Connection.connect @ strophe.js:2335$scope.login @ app.js:162fn @ VM233:4Ic.(anonymous function).compile.d.on.f @ angular.js:23411$get.n.$eval @ angular.js:15916$get.n.$apply @ angular.js:16016(anonymous function) @ angular.js:23416n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3
>   strophe.js:2784 7

```
 username=$cookies.get('username');
//alert(username);
if (username!=undefined) {

    var v_jid=username+'@v.com';
    if (global_isMobile) {
        v_jid=username+'@v.com';
    }
    else{
        v_jid=username+'@v.com';
    }
    var v_password=username;

    var conn = new Strophe.Connection("/http-bind/");
      alert(v_jid);
    conn.connect(v_jid, v_password, function (status) {

        if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {

            Vaster.connection = conn;
            console.log('connected');
            $scope.v_con=true;

            if ($scope.v_con) {
                if (global_isMobile) {
                    $(document).trigger('connected');
                    $location.path('/Chats.html');
                    $scope.$apply();
                    $timeout(function () {
                     // 0 ms delay to reload the page.
                      $route.reload();
                    }, 0);
                 }
                 else{
                    //alert($scope.v_con);
                    $(document).trigger('connected');
                    $location.path('/Chat.html');
                    $scope.$apply();
                    //$scope.$digest();
                 }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('disconnected');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post some code or something what would help us to help you

Comment: Is your server hosted on localhost?

Comment: yes.Server is hosted on localhost and I have also set proxypass for http-bind/ still its not working.